# Create extra columns that count cumulative occurrences grouped by another column

Tags: pandas

I've got a df that looks like this with duplicate ID's

```
     ID    Usage_type
0     5    Note
1     6    Note
2     7    Service
3     5    Note
4     7    Note
5     10   Service
```

I want an extra two columns that indicate the cumulative count of usage_type for each ID like so:

```
     ID    Usage_type   type_Note    type_Service
0     5    Note         1            0
1     6    Note         1            0
2     7    Service      0            1
3     5    Note         2            0
4     7    Note         1            1
5     10   Service      0            1
```

I've got code that counts the total number of values for the Usage_type column for each ID but want to separate the two types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `get_dummies` and `groupby` with `cumsum`

```
df = df.join(df.Usage_type.str.get_dummies().groupby(df.ID).cumsum())
df
Out[80]: 
   ID Usage_type  Note  Service
0   5       Note     1        0
1   6       Note     1        0
2   7    Service     0        1
3   5       Note     2        0
4   7       Note     1        1
5  10    Service     0        1
```

Comment: I tried your solution but get a syntax error. I'm not sure where it is though